# Insert affected rows to temp table before inserting using Merge Statement SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: logging, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-statement

I created the following `MERGE` statement and it is working as expected.

Unfortunately, I need to modify this merge statement due to new requirement.  Before inserting/updating/deleting via `MERGE` statement, I need to capture rows into a third table. Once reviewed by users, I can then push my changes to TARGET table.

Is this possible with the `MERGE` statement?

```
MERGE INTO LARBI_Dim AS TARGET
USING (SELECT *  
       FROM #LARBI_Dim_view) AS SOURCE ON  SOURCE.RefLeaseAssumptionID = TARGET.RefLeaseAssumptionID

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
   THEN         
      INSERT ([RefLeaseAssumptionID], isLinkedFlag, isExtendedFlag)
      VALUES (SOURCE.[RefLeaseAssumptionID], SOURCE.isLinkedFlag, SOURCE.isExtendedFlag)

WHEN MATCHED AND
        (SOURCE.isLinkedFlag <>  TARGET.isLinkedFlag
         OR SOURCE.isExtendedFlag <>  TARGET.isExtendedFlag)
   THEN
      UPDATE
         SET TARGET.isLinkedFlag = SOURCE.isLinkedFlag,
             TARGET.isExtendedFlag = SOURCE.isExtendedFlag

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
   THEN
      DELETE

OUTPUT $ACTION,
    getdate() as 'ChangedDate',
    Isnull(inserted.[RefLeaseAssumptionID], deleted.[RefLeaseAssumptionID]) as 'RefLeaseAssumptionID',
    CASE WHEN $ACTION = 'UPDATE' AND inserted.isLinkedFlag <> deleted.isLinkedFlag
        THEN cast(deleted.isLinkedFlag as varchar(30)) + '-->' + cast(inserted.isLinkedFlag as varchar(30))
        END as 'isLinkedFlag',

    CASE WHEN $ACTION = 'UPDATE' AND inserted.isExtendedFlag <> deleted.isExtendedFlag
        THEN cast(deleted.isExtendedFlag as varchar(30)) + '-->' + cast(inserted.isExtendedFlag as varchar(30))
        END as 'isExtendedFlag'

        ;
```

Comment: Ouch, MERGE with no holdlock? This could be bad. You should check this article for other potential issues, too: [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) Anyway if you need human intervention to "okay" rows in the temp table, this seems like two isolated steps that can't be accomplished in one step, with or without merge, and how would you account for data that has changed in these tables in the meantime?

Comment: Hi Aaron,  issue is this is our current process with our current system.  We are soon switching to a new system and will be feeding data to that system.  The new system requires creation of .csv file (which will create from third table created from OUTPUT).  Once it is confirmed data looks good, merge statement will also insert/update/delete into a current table (as a backup plan).  Every night, this table will be fully loaded into new system, while third table gets loaded as often as every 15 minutes interval.